# How may Celery be configured for port 55672 instead of 15672? (Celery 3.1 vs RabbitMQ 2.7: [Errno 111] Connection refused)

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

Without changing versions of software, how may Celery 3.1 be configured to use port 55672 to access rabbitmq instead of the default 15672?

### Situation

RabbitMQ versions 2.* use port 55672 for the management plugin, but Kombu 3.0 defaults to using port 15672 to access the management plugin. (RabbitMQ versions 3.* use port 15672.)

### Evidence

The celery command line tool receives `[Errno 111] Connection refused`.

```
<!-- language: bash -->
$ celery list bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
...snip...
pyrabbit.http.NetworkError: Error: <class 'socket.error'>
```

The Python debugger shows celery trying to connect to the wrong port: 15672. That's the port for RabbitMQ 3.0+ versions of the Management plugin.

```
(demo-celery-flask) $ python -m pdb ~/.virtualenvs/demo-celery-flask/bin/celery list bindings
> /home/zeb/.virtualenvs/demo-celery-flask/bin/celery(4)<module>()
-> import re
(Pdb) continue
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...snip content...
NetworkError: Error: <class 'socket.error'> [Errno 111] Connection refused
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /home/zeb/.virtualenvs/demo-celery-flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrabbit/http.py(104)do_call()
-> raise NetworkError("Error: %s %s" % (type(out), out))
(Pdb) list 95,104
95             try:
96                 resp, content = self.client.request(url,
97                                                     reqtype,
98                                                     body,
99                                                     headers)
...snip content...
102             except Exception as out:
103                 # net-related exception types from httplib2 are unpredictable.
104  ->             raise NetworkError("Error: %s %s" % (type(out), out))
(Pdb) print url
'http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/bindings'
```

The string '15672' shows up in kombu's codebase as the default for a parameter called manager_port.

```
(demo-celery-flask)~/.virtualenvs/demo-celery-flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ rgrep 15672 celery/*
(demo-celery-flask)~/.virtualenvs/demo-celery-flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ rgrep 15672 kombu/*
...snip content...
kombu/utils/amq_manager.py:    port = port if port is not None else opt('manager_port', 15672)
```

---

Searching `site:docs.celeryproject.org manager_port` shows that it's part of the kombu.Connection object. Neither `15672` nor `55672` shows up in a site search.

The celery configuration [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html) does not mention `manager`. (Celery v3.1, 2014-08-02)

### Versions

- Ubuntu 12.04 (yes, it *should* be 14.04)
- Celery 3.1 (Cipater)
- Kombu 3.0.12
- RabbitMQ 2.7.1

RabbitMQ Management plugin is enabled and accessible via the rabbitmqadmin commandline at port 55672.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"manager_port": 55672}` to the celery configuration module.

---

Finding this involved the following steps:

- inspect `kombu/util/amq_manager.py` file where 15672 showed up as `opt('manager_port', 15672)`
- note that opt derived from `opt = client.transport_options.get`
- web search `site:docs.celeryproject.org transport_options`
- find `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}` in the redis transport documentation
- guess and check using `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"manager_port": 55672}`